# auto resize navigation bar on window resize or mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have found the code for this: http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/index.html menu here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/

and i am trying to do it with my menu:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#trans-nav {list-style-type: none; height: 40px; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#trans-nav { list-style-type: none; height: 40px; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#trans-nav li { float: left; position: relative; padding: 0; line-height: 40px; }
#trans-nav li:hover { background-position: 0 -40px; }
#trans-nav li a { display: block; padding: 0 15px; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; }
#trans-nav li a:hover { background-color:#F36F25; color: #eeeeee; }
#trans-nav li ul { opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 8em; background: #EEEEEE; list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#trans-nav li:hover ul { opacity: 1; }
#trans-nav li ul li { float: none; position: static; height: 0; line-height: 0; background: none; }
#trans-nav li:hover ul li { height: 30px; line-height: 30px; }
#trans-nav li ul li a { background: #EEEEEE; }
#trans-nav li ul li a:hover { background: #666666; color:#EEEEEE; }

#trans-nav li { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; }
#trans-nav li a { -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; }
#trans-nav li ul { -webkit-transition: all 1s; }
#trans-nav li ul li { -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="trans-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Thingamabobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Doohickies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

for some reason i cannot get it working, any ideas what i can do to make my menu the same as the one on that website or alternatively, if that will be too complicated to get my menu to just change to a dropdown menu (select) on screen resize

Answer (score 1):

You want to **css media query**

A media query consists of a media type and at least one expression that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as width, height, and color. Added in CSS3, media queries let the presentation of content be tailored to a **specific range of output devices without having to change the content itself.**

More details

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Ah yes. I thought it was that but I don't think I really understand it. Hve you got any examples?

Comment: http://alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html It's a css media query sample .You can adjest zoom level and see the changes

Comment: There's nothing about CSS on that link?